# SuiteScript nlapiLoadRecord throws Network error Failed to execute "send" on XMLhttpRequest

Tags: javascript, netsuite, suitescript

I have client script that calls nlapiLoadRecord and puts it in a variable

`var z = nlapiLoadRecord("test", 881)`

It is inside a field changed function that will be put in an online form.
But whenever I try to trigger it it shows this:
[Network Error Failed alert box.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D4USy.png)

Not having a type or id will throw the normal error messages but having them both will trigger the error above.

Comment: Have you tried it with native record types such as 'customer' for example?

Comment: @IgorPo Yes I have, it still throws the error. I understand that online forms cannot access records as bknights pointed out. I just want to access information from a record to use in computations in my online form. Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably cannot do this like you are thinking. Netsuite does not generally allow online form users to load records directly. For an online form what I normally do is create a suitelet that can return the custom record's info as JSON. If you are trying to access a custom record you can try going to the custom record and setting its access to use a permissions list then give the "Online Form User" read permissions for the record. This may work and is likely ok as long as you only plan to use the custom record as a lookup.

In general for this the usual suspects are:

- Does the user you are running as have the custom lists permission? That's pretty unlikely given that you are calling this from an online form.
- Use a real record id. A custom record id will begin with "customrecord" and may be found under Customization -> Lists, Records, Fields -> Record Types. Native record ids may be found through the help but I find it useful to bookmark the [latest release](https://system.netsuite.com/help/helpcenter/en_US/srbrowser/Browser2017_1/script/record/salesorder.html)

Comment: Hello, thank you for the reply. I just want to get the values from a field of a different custom record ( A -> B). I added a permission list to A and the online form is in B when I tried to load the record it still throws the error. Is there a simpler way to get values from records using online forms? Thank you for the help!